# Change Keycloak 21.1 (Quarkus) admin UI using SPI

Tags: console, keycloak, customization, admin

How can I change Keycloak 21.1 (Quarkus) admin UI using keycloak SPI, Whether it is possible to modify existing keycloak admin console UI using SPI.

e.g If I want to add extra button like download(besides refresh button) in event page how I can add this functionality in Keycloak.

Appreciate your input on this, Thanks

development of our customize module